# How to call Stripe.createPaymentMethod if you aren't using Stripe Elements?

Tags: stripe-payments

Looking at [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-payment-method) for the `createPaymentMethod` method of the PaymentIntents Api from Stripe, the second argument is expected to be an Element from Stripe Elements.

But I'm not using Stripe Elements, and I know that the PaymentIntents API doesn't require you to be using it....at least I was nearly certain of that, it wouldn't make sense.

So what am I supposed to pass to this method instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe requires that you use Elements client-side to collect card details. This ensures that you are PCI compliant as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).

While it was possible in the past with Stripe.js v2 to collect the card details on your end and then pass those, this puts you under a higher PCI scope and is not something Elements supports today.

It is still possible to send raw card details if that's what you need but you would have to talk to Stripe's support team about your use-case. You can contact them [here](https://support.stripe.com/contact).